# Unknown class in interface builder + NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, today-extension

I'm building a today extension, which works fine on iOS13+ but somehow it doesn't work for the versions below.

On other versions I get following error:

```
2019-12-20 08:45:41.741 MyWidget[4730:53043] Unknown class _TtC14MyWidget19TodayViewController in Interface Builder file.

2019-12-20 08:45:41.850 MyWidget[4730:53043] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7ffe59401f10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key loginViewNew.'
```

At first I thought it was caused, because in the properties under Interface Builder Document builds for was set to iOS13 and later, so I changed this in my storyboard and all my other .xib files but this did not solve the problem, I still get the same error.

I also checked my outlets and there are no errors there as well, storyboard can find my `TodayViewController` class so I have no clue what the problem can be.

It does not only occur for the key `loginViewNew`, if I delete that outlet the error mentions the next view and so on.

Does anyone have suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: Clear Derive data, clean the build, restart xcode and then try....

Comment: please check `IBOutlet` connections. is there any connection with yellow color exclamation mark?

Comment: Check the module of the ViewController `MyWidgetTodayViewController` in InterfaceBuilder? Or check that this class is correctly inside your Widget target

Comment: @Larme thank you, the module was inherited from the target and for some reason that caused the error. I unchecked the box to inherit and left the module blank and that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Some cases generate an `Unknown class in Interface Builder file` after *Xcode 11* with a target below *iOS 13*. The main cause it's related to **xcframeworks** this is so expected because when building a framework for distribution required changes to the Objective-C runtime that are only available in *iOS 13* and *later*. The following samples on how to reproduce the *unknown class*.

- public *enum* exported by *framework* and used as *attribute* on *class*:

```swift
// SampleEnum exported on framework
public enum SampleEnum: String {
  case A = "a"
  case B = "b"
}

// SampleViewController on your current target
public class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
  private var sampleEnum: SampleEnum = .A
}

// Causes Unknown class _TtC6Sample20SampleViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

- *inheritance* of *inheritance* as:

```swift
// Base BaseViewControoler exported on framework
public class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
}

// ScreenAViewController on your current project
public class ScreenAViewController: BaseViewController {
}

// Causes Unknown class _TtC6Sample21ScreenAViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

- small issues on interface builder on ***Show the Identify inspector*** section ***Custom Class*** fields:

*Class*

*Module*

*Inherit Module From Target*